# How to find where winsock.h is included in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have duplicate definition in my project for winsock2, I know it's about `winsock.h` is included in windows.h and I have to include `winsock2.h` before windows.h and winsock.h, but I've done and still have the errors.
EDIT : I also tried `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` with the same problem.

How can I find where `winsock.h` is included, isn't there a "inclusion tree" somewhere ?

I erased winsock.h and it works, but I don't like that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before `#include <windows.h>` to not pull in winsock1.

Comment: Already trie that.

Comment: You have to define it before every inclusion of `windows.h`. The best way to do that would be to pass it as a compiler argument.